# Return custom XML from Web Api HttpRequestMessage.CreateResponse

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I need to return xml from my mvc 4 web api, it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
     <success/>
</response>
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "success", Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

And the xml it returns looks like this, which doesn't meet the client's requirements:

```
<string>success</string>
```

Is there a way to achieve my desired result?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to set config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.WriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false; in WebApiConfig.cs file to see <?xml version="1.0" > tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining a `Reponse` class and have your web api return a `CreateResponse<Response>` instead:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="response")]
public class Response
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string success { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Will this response include <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> at the beginning of the xml?

Comment: Yes, the xml header is there.  Note that default encoding is UTF 8 and  so that attribute is not there in the header.

Comment: @TrevorBrooks You need to set config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.WriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false; in WebApiConfig.cs file to see <?xml version="1.0" > tag.